# Can't translate elasticsearch query into pyes

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes

I need your help to translate a query into pyes. This query is working properly, the problem is that I can't use pyes to make it work:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/user/_search?pretty=1' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "bool":{
            "should": [
               { "text": { "first_name": "em" }},
               { "text": { "first_name.partial": "em" }}
             ]
        }
    }
}'
```

First I was doing this, according to [0.17 docs](http://packages.python.org/pyes/):

```
q1 = TextQuery("first_name","em")
q2 = TextQuery("first_name.partial","em")
q = BoolQuery(should=[q1, q2])
conn.search(q,indices='my_index',doc_types='user')
```

After a few exceptions raised, i realized that i've installed 0.16, because 0.17 is an unstable branch.

So, to put it simple: How can I translate search that query with pyes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible to translate your query into pyes 0.16. As you can see the TextQuery constructor in 0.16 doesn't have the field parameter:  https://github.com/aparo/pyes/blob/109f84696153f3be474e1d7d261776a1bca04570/pyes/query.py#L856 and it seem to generate invalid elasticsearch queries. On the other side your code should work fine in 0.17.